# jQuery can't parse JSON built with Ruby-JSON

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby, ajax

I'm trying to set up an Ajax callback using jQuery, and it's just not working. My Ruby code looks something like this:

```
return {:one => some_html, :two => more_html}.to_json
```

When it gets to the client jQuery bails saying "parse error". If I make it something really simple, like:

```
return {:one => 'Something', :two => 'Something else'}.to_json
```

Then it works just fine. I guess I'm just wondering how it is that a library whose only job is to create JSON, could create invalid JSON? Or is it something else?

Answer (score 2):

Is it possible the some_html & more_html has characters in it which are interfering with jQuery's parsing of the JSON? Have you used [Firebug](http://getfirebug.com/) to view the AJAX response and ensure that it's valid JSON?

Comment: Actually, it looks like Ramaze is unescaping the quotes in my JSON, which is breaking everything.

Comment: Got it! You need to use "respond('text')" to get Ramaze to not use a template. I'm not sure what to do with this question now, since it's pretty worthless now...

Answer (score 0):

You are probably not parsing it correctly, although I can't tell because you did not post the code.  Use the [JSON javascript parser](http://www.json.org/js.html) to do this.  It takes care of potential script injections, although this is usually good enough for me...

```
var json = eval(" (" + httpResponse + ") ");
```